# open source crm with desktop sync

Tags: open-source, offline, synchronization, crm, contact-manager

We are looking for a free and open source crm to manage contacts, with the ability to have all of the data synced to the local desktop for offline use.

Essential features:

- ability to manage contacts
- ability to create custom fields
- offline interface
- central database with sync
- multiple users with different permissions
- must be reliable
- low maintenance

Non-essential features (but would be used):

- web interface
- calendar
- mobile apps
- export data to excel spreadsheets

Not needed:

- marketing features
- sales and leads

The budget for this is quite low, as we currently have something (commence CRM). We want to upgrade for compatibility reasons, and are looking for a lower cost solution.

Comment: If it weren't for the custom fields, [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) would cover that fine. Including native clients for many OSes (desktop and mobile), as well as your non-essential features.

Comment: Custom fields are essential